# log4j2.xml file being loaded too late

Tags: java, maven, logging, log4j2

I have a jar generated by maven that includes all the necessary dependencies. In the root of this jar I have the log4j2.xml configuration file. I execute the jar with the command "java -cp myJar.jar myClass". At this point my app will run without problem, but I will get the following logj4 error output on the console:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (myClass).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

What is interesting is that my log4j2.xml file is parsed and used at some point, because the file it will use for logging is created. It just seems that it is parsed and setup too late in the process.

I've only included log4j2 dependencies, though I do have the bridge in case a dependency was using log4j. Also, this works locally when I test in eclipse. It is only when I package it into a jar that it stops working.

Comment: In your example, you don't have log4j on your classpath.

Comment: Log4j is in my classpath, just in the jar. As I mentioned the jar has all the dependencies package with it.

To add more context, I removed all the bridge dependencies and found my code was using the v1.2 libraries. By changing them to the 2.0 namespace version I got the output I expected from my libraries. Still this seems to be poor behavior, as those libraries are supposed to make it so v1.2 stuff gets routed to v2.0. The key issue  is "mvn java:exec" and executing the jar created by "mvn package", should function the same.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is what happens when Maven packages together a jar with all its dependencies. If there are any dependencies that overlap (i.e., log4j and log4j-1.2-api) then one of them will be added to the jar and the other will be excluded. This is done silently. It is also inconsistent with "mvn exec:java".

To ensure log4j is not package you need to go through your dependencies and add

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

to each dependency that could include log4j. This will prevent it from being loaded into the jar, ensuring that only log4j2 will run. You need to be vigilant, as any time you add a dependency you need to assure it doesn't have log4j as a transient depency.

Eventually you should be able to add a global exlusion (http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-1977?jql=text%20~%20%22global%20exclusion%22), but for now this is what you have to do.

Comment: I concur with Mathflair. The error above is generated by the log4j-1.2 implementation. If you want to use the log4j-1.2 api but the log4j-2.0 implementation you must make sure that the log4j-1.2 jar is not in your classpath.